# Rails 4 - mail is not delivered if is sent to multiple recipients (using Sendgrid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sendgrid

I want to send a message with my products to users signed up to my application couple times a day.
Here's a mailer method I use for that:

```
  def notify_users(product)  
    @product
    emails  = Customer.signed_up.pluck(:email_address)
    puts "EMAILS:"
    puts emails.inspect # I see here, say, 5 email addresses
    emails.each do |email|
      unless email.blank?
        puts "Sending to #{email}" # email is displayed here properly
        mail(to: email, subject: "New products", from: 'no-reply@website.com') 
      end                     
    end
```

What I found out is that if `emails` contains only 1 email address, the email is delivered on the email address. But when I do send the email on multiple email addresses, usually is delivered only the last message (so if `emails` continues `["a@gmail.com", "b@gmail.com", "c@gmail.com"]`), so the email is delivered only on `c@gmail.com`.

Why is that? Trying to find out the reason of that, but still unsuccessful.

Comment: what is the use of the code unless email.blank? just try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
def send_notification_to_user(email)
  puts "Sending to #{email}" # email is displayed here properly
  mail(to: email, subject: "New products", from:'no-reply@website.com') 
end

def notify_users(product)  
  @product
  emails  = Customer.signed_up.pluck(:email_address)
  puts "EMAILS:"
  puts emails.inspect # I see here, say, 5 email addresses
  emails.each do |email|
    unless email.blank?
      send_notification_to_user(email).deliver_now 
    end                     
  end
end
```